# Definition of holomorphic functions in multiple dimensions

Tags: complex-analysis, definition, several-complex-variables

What is the definition of a function
$$f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^n$$
being holomorphic? Where $U\subseteq\mathbb{C}^n$.

When I look around online all I can see is the definition for
$$f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$$
to be holomorphic. Such as $f$ being holomorphic in each variable $z_i$ (i.e. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z_i}}=0$ where $\frac{\partial }{\partial \bar{z_i}}$ is the Wirtinger derivative.

Is it associated with the concept of total derivative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $f : \Bbb{C^n \to C^m}$ is holomorphic on an open set $U$ iff for every $a \in U,v\in \Bbb{C^n}$, $D_{iv} f(a) = i D_v f(a)$ where $D_v f(a) = \lim_{t \to 0,t \in \Bbb{R}} \frac{f(a+tv)-f(a)}{t}$ is the directional derivative.

$U$ must be open in the complex topology.

The directional derivative is $\Bbb{R}$-linear in $v$ whenever $f$ is differentiable on $U$, holomorphy means it is $\Bbb{C}$-linear.

For $m=n$ the holomorphy means the Jacobian matrix of $(\Re(f),\Im(f))$ lies in the subalgebra of $M_{2n}(\Bbb{R})$ corresponding to $M_n(\Bbb{C})$.

For simplicity let $U \subset \Bbb{C}^2$, $f$ be holomorphic $U\to \Bbb{C}$ and $(a,b) \in U$ and $U$ be containing $\{ (u,v)\in \Bbb{C^2}, |u-a| \le r, |v-b| \le R\}$ then by the usual Cauchy integral formula

> for $(z,w)\in \Bbb{C^2},|z-a| < r, |w-b| < R$
>    $$f(z,w) = \frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{|u-a|=r} \frac{f(u,w)}{u-z}du=\frac{1}{(2i\pi)^2}\int_{|u-a|=r} \int_{|v-b|=R}\frac{f(u,v)}{(u-z)(v-w)}dudv$$
>   which is analytic by expanding the denominators in geometric series in $z,w$.

Comment: I'm slightly confused, Wikipedia talks about the directional derivative of a scalar function. Is it the same here, even though we're dealing with vector functions?

Comment: That $m=1$ or not doesn't change anything.

Comment: So would it be sufficient (or even equivalent) that each component function is holomorphic as a map to $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Sure. Also the Cauchy integral formula shows if $f$ is continuous then it [suffices that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osgood%27s_lemma) it is holomorphic in each variable separately.

Comment: @reuns Does it not suffice to say that a map $f : U \to \mathbb{C}^m$ defined by $z \mapsto (f_1(z), ..., f_m(z))$ is holomorphic if and only if each $f_j : U \to \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic?

Comment: That $f$ is $U \to \Bbb{C}^m$ or $U \to \Bbb{C}$ doesn't change anything in term of continuity, differentiability, smoothness, holomorphy, analyticity. The point is to distinguish between the function in all the variables and in one of the variables while keeping the other fixed.